# "Клюнул жареный петух"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Откуда пошло выражение "клюнул жареный петух", да еще и в мягкое место...
Я понимаю его так: пришла беда. Есть еще значения? Петух может разозлиться и клюнуть, но почему он жареный? Есть связь с пожаром?

Answer (score 2):

Русский человек начинает действовать только в минуту крайней опасности, которую символизирует **совершенно фантастическая ситуация:** жареный петух оживает и очень больно клюется, причем в самые чувствительные места.

Итак, жареный петух ― **это символ, образ**, мы же можем объяснить, с чем он связан.

Есть еще похожее выражение ― **жареным запахло**.  Оно означает непосредственную (обычно ― смертельную) опасность для того, кому "пахнет". Обычно данное выражение "выводят" **из костров инквизиции**. Возможна и альтернативная трактовка, популярная среди тех, кто часто ночует **у костра**... https://otvet.mail.ru/question/198097828

**Красный гребень петуха символизировал пламя.** В русском языке еще существовало такое выражение: пустить петуха, т.е. устроить пожар.

Рассерженные петухи вообще больно клюются, а уже если его зажарить, то он будет **особенно сердит**. К тому ***жареный*** ― это не обязательно ***зажаренный***, возможно, что петух остался жив, но при этом очень напуган и зол.

**Кто же может оживить жареного петуха?** Наверное, какие-то фантастические силы (добрые или злые). Интересные истории об этом рассказаны здесь. http://znaniya2011.ru/istoriya-vyirazheniya-poka-zharenyiy-petuh-ne-klyunet

**Примеры из литературы:**

Русский человек известно, чего-то дожидается и не берется за дело со всей душой, пока **в слабое место** жареный петух не укусит. [М. М. Пришвин. Дневники (1928)]

Очень хорошо вами, Гольц, сказано: когда жареный петух **запоет ку-ку-ре-ку**… [В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. Книга первая. Ч. 1-2 (1934-1939)]

― это жалкое высокомерие тех, кого, по их счастью, жареный петух не клевал в **непоротые задницы**. (С. Б. Рассадин. Книга прощаний. Воспоминания о друзьях и не только).

― Потому что жареный петух его еще **в маковку** не клевал! [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. За миллиард лет до конца света (1974)]

Answer (score 1):

По поводу других значений. В некоторых словарях значение связано с невозможностью события. В [этой статье](http://russkayarech.ru/files/issues/2012/6/16-voznesenskaya.pdf) кандидата филологических наук Л.Л. Вознесенской эти два значения связаны в одно целое:

> Во фразеологизме *пока жареный петух не клюнет* своеобразно отражается
>   свойственная петухам агрессивность. Выражение значит «пока не
>   произойдут реальные неприятности, не настанут настоящие трудности,
>   которые должны были наступить, но которых, тем не менее, никто не
>   ожидал», т.е. указывает на почти нереальное, но все-таки
>   осуществленное действие: «Тебя еще не клюнул в задницу жареный петух,
>   Славочка, чистый, пригожий ты мой мальчик» (С. Есин. Имитатор).

С этой точки зрения распространённая ("народная"?) этимология, связанная с пожаром, выглядит подозрительно. Но сколько-нибудь надёжного источника найти не удалось.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный ответ. Но еще хотелось бы понять, почему он жареный.

Comment: @М_Г По логике автора цитаты получается, что "жареный" подчёркивает невозможность события. Мне сложно поверить в эту логику без убедительных аргументов, но поскольку она звучит от профессионала, я склонен принять её за основу. Отмечу ещё одно любопытное наблюдение: едва ли не большинство комментаторов в сети единственный смысл фразеологизма видят в нереальности события и считают этот фразеологизм полным аналогом "свистящего рака". Это меня удивило.

Comment: Я слышал это выраженое в том же смысле, что и "Пока гром не грянет, мужик не перекрестится"

Comment: @М_Г Да, и я до вчерашнего дня воспринимал его так же. Теперь понимание чуть уточнилось, но всё равно осталось в том же духе.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я не считаю корректным править цитаты из статей, если в них нет явных ошибок (даже если есть — это отдельный вопрос). Я вернул запятые на место и предлагаю Вам посмотреть ответ грамоты.ру на [этот вопрос](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=252235).

Comment: Ну, как знаете.

Answer (score 1):

А я нашла такое (далее - всё цитата, от меня - шрифтовые выделения):

---

***[Сегодня речь пойдет о терпеливом жареном петухе.](http://znaniya2011.ru/istoriya-vyirazheniya-poka-zharenyiy-petuh-ne-klyunet)***

Помните это выражение: «Пока жареный петух не клюнет»? Немного непонятно, правда?

Как может клеваться уже практически зажаренное мясо?

Но надо учитывать, что не всё так просто в этом выражении.

Все, кто бывал в деревне, видели, конечно, этого хозяина курятника и любимца всех дворовых кур. Он действительно чувствует себя хозяином и защитником.

А попробуйте-ка на глазах у петуха замахнуться на какую-нибудь курицу… или на маленьких цыплят.

Что тут начнется!.. Ведь петух не посмотрит, что вы человек, что сильнее и больше его в несколько раз. ***Его гребень при этом поднимается, как знамя.*** И сам он становится таким грозным и, кстати сказать, очень опасным. Стоит только разозлить петуха, мало вам не покажется. Больно клевать он умеет. А в мирное время он добрый и заботливый семьянин.

***Вот этот грозный гребень и символизировал пламя. В русском языке еще существовало такое выражение: пустить петуха, т. е. устроить пожар.***  Вы, наверное, не раз встречали его в литературе. И вот ***когда все имущество сгорало, говорили, что у такого-то барина во дворе жареный петух, т. е. ничего, кроме пепла не осталось.***

*Вот тогда и приходилось начинать жизнь с нуля.*

---

**Уточнение.**

В процитированном мини-сочинении маленькая, но досадная ошибка:

***Пустить петуха*** означает: *сорвавшись на высокой ноте во время пения, издать пискливые звуки* ©.

***Пустить красного петуха*** -

**поджечь**

◆ *Как тут повысить производительность сельскохозяйственного труда посредством уничтожения крестьянской общины, если столоначальник украл подъемные деньги, урядник пропил общественное стадо, бедняк желает подпустить процветающему соседу «красного петуха»…* В. А. Пьецух, «Уроки родной истории (Пособие для юношества, агностиков и вообще) // «Октябрь»», 2003 г.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Однако... В словаре на Академике - "придавать проблемам достаточное внимание", О_о...)